# What is the origin and purpose of RS_##.log files?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, logging

On my Galaxy S3 (I747, rooted stock ROM, 4.1.1 jellybean), there are a number (currently 66) of files in /data with names following the format RS_##.log, where ## is a 1 or 2 digit number, currently from 0 to 65.

All files are slightly less than 1KB in size and when viewed as text, contain nothing but strings of seemingly random 5 digit numbers, like these.
71608
70944
70096
70376
70944

All files are owned by system and have rw-rw-rw permissions set.

Most of the files have been updated recently (yesterday) and within 1 minute of each other.  The rest were updated just over 2 weeks ago, also all at once.

What exactly is creating these files and what exactly are they logging?

Comment: Could RS stand for "Random Seed"?  (Not posting as an Answer because it's pure speculation)

Comment: @Josh - I wouldn't think so.  Unless there's something I'm not considering, a random seed would only be written just before a reboot and the file timestamps don't correspond to any times I've rebooted the phone.